# jQuery dynamically created form doesn't allow click fire method on elements inside

Tags: forms, click, jquery

My final scope is to change a text in an input field once clicked, and consequently replace the `<div>` container with a `<form>` container.

But **after** form creation, click events are **not anymore fired**.

In this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erpreciso/jePS3/3/) I posted only the form creation and function to check the fire on divs.
Any thoughts?

(also any suggestions and comments to improve code readability and efficiency are always well accepted, I'm a newbie).

Stefano

Code:
**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="pubbl">
        <div id="title"><h1>A sentence</h1></div>
        <div id="content">“Age is my alarm clock,” the old man said. “Why do old men wake so early? Is it to have one longer day?”
“I don’t know,” the boy said. “All I know is that young boys sleep late and hard”. Ernest Hemingway.</div>
    </div>
</body>
<button id="btn">show html</button>
<button id="cr">create form</button>
```

Code: **JavaScript**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    alert($("body").html());
    alert(there_is_form());
});

$("#cr").click(function(){
    crea_form();
});

$("#title").click(function(){
    alert("title fired");
});
$("#content").click(function(){
    alert("content fired");
});

function crea_form(){
    alert("function create form fired");
    if (there_is_form()) { return; };
    var test_div = document.getElementById('pubbl');
    var cont = test_div.innerHTML;
    test_div.innerHTML = '';    
    var form = test_div.appendChild(document.createElement('form'));
    form.name = 'input';
    form.action = 'target-etc';
    form.method = 'post';
    form.innerHTML = cont;
    input = form.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    input.type = 'submit';
    input.value = 'Submit';
};

function there_is_form(){
    return document.getElementsByTagName("form").length > 0;
};
```

Comment: Your both button working fine after creating form, then what you want to do..?

Comment: @Neeraj thank for your comment. Buttons always worked, no problem in that, the two <div> that had the click method were not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click',"#btn",function(){
        alert($("body").html());
        alert(there_is_form());
    });
    $(document).on('click',"#cr",function(){
        crea_form();
    });

    $(document).on('click',"#title",function(){
        alert("title fired");
    });
    $(document).on('click',"#content",function(){
        alert("content fired");
    });
});
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/on